# Microsoft WSL2 virtual network adapter settings to allow 802.1Q tagged raw Ethernet packets travel between host and WSL Linux

Tags: networking, ethernet, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, 802.1q

We need to send raw Ethernet packets with 802.1Q tags from Windows -using Npcap- to WSL Linux and vice-versa. But the packets do not reach the other side. We are using Ubuntu-20.04 on top of WSL2. On Linux side we are checking the packets with tcpdump; on Windows, with WireShark.

The tag we are using is not a *VLAN tag*, but a *priority tag* (VLAN ID = 0):

```
VLAN_TPID=0x8100
VLAN_TCI=0x4000 (PCP=2, CFI=0, VID=0)
```

If we remove the tag, raw Ethernet packets reach the other end without issues. When we add it, we stop seeing the packets in "the other side". Thus we suspect the virtual network adapter configuration.

We find the virtual adapter name by

```
PS>Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS

Name                   IsManagementOs VMName SwitchName     MacAddress   Status IPAddresses
----                   -------------- ------ ----------     ----------   ------ -----------
Container NIC 2e844c66 True                  Default Switch 00155D1F063A {Ok}
Container NIC 46298210 True                  WSL            00155DBAC80C {Ok}
```

The one corresponding to the WSL Switch is `Container NIC 46298210`.

Then, we try these two PowerShell commands:

```
PS>Set-VMNetworkAdapterVlan -ManagementOS -VMNetworkAdapterName "Container NIC 46298210" -Trunk -AllowedVlanIdList "0,1-255" -NativeVlanId 0

PS>Set-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS -VMNetworkAdapterName "Container NIC 46298210" -IeeePriorityTag On
```

But still our 802.1Q tagged Ethernet packets do not traverse Windows<->Linux.

Any idea on how we can proceed?

Comment: You might get further with WSL1 which doesn't use Hyper-V or virtual hardware. Network applications under WSL1 are running on the Windows network itself without NAT.

Comment: @harrymc, I tried but WSL1 seems not to support the full Linux socket API. I get error 97 on socket creation: _Address family not supported by protocol_ in response to
`fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));`

Comment: Try running WSL1 as Administrator.

Comment: I tried this way:
  1. run PowerShell as Administrator
  2. launch wsl as root: `PS>wsl --distribution Ubuntu-20.04-WSL1 --user root
  3. launch test app: `#sudo ./tester`

but I get same error code.
[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1628) it states that WSL(1) does not support AF_PACKET.

Comment: Perhaps [this method](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4928#issuecomment-646703350) can be useful. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74205120/165358). Just to note that you will not have these kind of problems with a Linux VM.

Comment: Hi, that was an answer from me : ). But unfortunately, for 802.1Q tagged packets, it does not work.

Comment: @harrymc, as you suggested, I tried Linux on Virtual Box. After setting the adapter to "Host-only", I achieve two way communication with and without 802.1Q tags. But still, I'd like to see this working on WSL2, too.

Comment: WSL2 is just a stripped-down Linux VM (perhaps stripped down too much).

Comment: I get a similar problem using a RHEL7 VM on a full Windows Hyper-V server.   So maybe a problem with Hyper-V.